# Stream.Dispose() method and FillAccess.Write Issue(?)

Tags: c#, file, stream, filestream, binaryformatter

I'm writing a program using what I understand is a flat-file database. In my program, I deserialize a set of objects which I will be working with in the program, and load those objects into a list.

```
            using (FileStream IStreamRead = new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + itemFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            if (IStreamRead.Length > 0)
                itemRecords = bformatter.Deserialize(IStreamRead) as List<Record>;
        }
        using (FileStream CStreamRead = new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + clinicFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            if (CStreamRead.Length > 0)
                clinicNames = bformatter.Deserialize(CStreamRead) as List<String>;
        }
```

Output stream delcaration (used to overwrite to the file):

```
        Istream = new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + itemFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        Cstream = new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + clinicFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
```

At the end of the program (when the user exits the application), I execute a Save method:

```
        private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //save the state of all record objects, as well as clinic names
        if (itemRecords.Count > 0)
            bformatter.Serialize(Istream, itemRecords);
        if (clinicNames.Count > 0)
            bformatter.Serialize(Cstream, clinicNames);
    }
```

The save method is called in the FormClosing event handler to ensure all objects are saved, but the user is prompted as well if any changes have been made.

```
        private void mainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataEdited)
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to save your edits?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender, e as EventArgs);
                Istream.Dispose();
                Cstream.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                Istream.Dispose();
                Cstream.Dispose();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Istream.Dispose();
            Cstream.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

The issue I'm running into is that information in the file is being deleted (or at least it seems that way) if I choose not to save the file. For example, I'll open up the application already having one clinic name saved in the clinic name file, but if I then close the application without saving, the clinic name will not be there the next time the application is opened. Is there something that happens when the stream is disposed which might cause this?

Comment: Any write stream you must flush() and close() otherwise you can loose data.

Comment: Calling `new FileStream()` with the `Create` FileMode option immediately replaces your existing file with a blank one. I'm having some trouble deciphering the rest of your program, but you possibly only want to create the stream inside the "save" handler, that way the file is never created *or overwritten* if they hit "No don't save". Once you call `New FileStream( .. FileMode.Create ...)` your existing file gets blasted.

Comment: @Quantic You're right, I was not aware of that. It makes sense now that I think about it though, since it's essentially creating a new file with the same name. I moved the stream declarations to the FormClosing method right before the save method is called, and now it functions perfectly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That is not it, FileStream is unusual and still flushes its buffer when you dispose.  The code is quite clumsy, there is no obvious reason to open the file early.  Other than writing to it while the user is interacting with the UI.  So clicking No will leave partial data in the file.  The Q+D workaround is to delete the files.  Do keep in mind that overwriting is not a good idea since clicking No will leave the user without any data.